# How to redirect after an email has been sent

Tags: php, html, email

I'm very new to PHP however, I have managed to get working an email system from a contact form on my front end of a webpage. The problem I have that once the email is sent, I wish to hide the form and display a message saying "thank you for the email."

I have tried to look for solutions, but the only answer I could find was to use this code: header("Location: sentmail.html"); From here then I redirect it to another HTML page, Identical to the contact page with the form removed. I feel this is bad practice as it will require many duping pages for how many contact forms are across the website.

Is there a way to display a "thank you for your message" Once the email has been sent rather then redirect to a sentmail.html page.

Thank you for taking the time to read.

```
`<?php
extract($_POST);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
$name = $_POST['first_name'];
$email = $_POST['email_address'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$mailTo = "jamie@sharpsdigital.co.uk";
$headers = "From: MLS systems Contact Form ";
$txt = "$name has sent you an email from the address. " .$email. "\n\n With the message of.\n\n" .$message. " \n\n This is an automated   response from the contact form, Please click on the blue email address above to respond." ;
mail ($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
header("Location: sentmail.html");
?>`
```

This is the PHP Code, and below the form code

```
<section class="free-appoinment-area">
    <div class="container">
        <form action="sendmail.php" method="post" class="free-appoinment-form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="sec-title text-left">
                        <h1>Any queries</h1><span class="decor"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="input-field">
                                <input name="first_name" placeholder="Your Name*" type="text">
                                <div class="icon-holder">
                                    <span class="flaticon-people"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="input-field">
                                <input name="subject" placeholder="Your Subject" type="text">
                                <div class="icon-holder">
                                    <span class="flaticon-people"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="input-field">
                                <input name="email_address" placeholder="Email Address*" type="text">
                                <div class="icon-holder">
                                    <span class="flaticon-note"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="input-field">
                                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message..."></textarea>
                                <div class="icon-holder comment">
                                    <span class="flaticon-social-1"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                             <button type="submit" data-type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with php and css.

the php way is by using **if else** statement, like bellow

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email_address'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $mailTo = "jamie@sharpsdigital.co.uk";
    $headers = "From: MLS systems Contact Form ";
    $txt = "$name has sent you an email from the address. " .$email. "\n\n With the message of.\n\n" .$message. " \n\n This is an automated   response from the contact form, Please click on the blue email address above to respond." ;
    if(mail ($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers)){
 echo "Thanks for your contact.";
}

}else{ ?>

your form goes here

<?php }?>
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfect, just one thing if I wish to add an href to link back to the home page to come full circle, do I just add an anchor tag after the speech mark but before the semi colon? So something like this?

echo "Thanks for your contact. \n\n" "Click <a href="index.html">Here</a> to return" ;

Comment: you welcome happy to solve your issue, you can add link like this: echo 'Thanks for your contact. </br> Click <a href="index.php">Here</a> to return';

Comment: if my answer solved your issue please up-vote it thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are hundreds of possibilities, but simply put, you can grab the return value of `mail()` and display contents according to this:

```
$success = mail('...');
```

#### form.php

```
if($success) {
    echo 'Thank you!';
} else {
    // output form here
}
```

Of course you can simply set a flag to true in your form handler too, but this is too broad to explain here.

Comment: So between $success = mail('...');  Should my $mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers be going there? And sorry but what should I be putting in the "output form here" comment?

Comment: @Jamie according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php, mail will return true or false. So $success will either be true or false. If it's true, output the thank you code. If not, output the form code.